# How to get Nested loop in batch file to run NET Command

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Hi

I am trying to run below code to get just user and  it's assigned global group

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=,"  %%a in ('net localgroup TectiaUsers^|findstr /b "EUR"') do (
set FID=%%~a
echo !FID!
PAUSE
set FID=!FID:EUR\=!
echo !FID!
PAUSE
for /f "useback tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%b in ('net user !FID! /domain^|findstr /b "Global Group memberships"') do (
    echo !FID!,%%~b
    PAUSE
)
)
```

now above code is not giving expected output, I have checked and found that when code    ***for /f "useback tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%b in ('net user !FID! /domain^|findstr /b "Global Group memberships"') do (
        echo !FID!,%%~b)*** it return the output as it is

```
 Press any key to continue . . .
 User1,net user User1 /domain|findstr /b "Global Group memberships"
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

Instead I am expecting output as below

```
Global Group memberships     *Domain Users
```

Comment: Try to escape the comma `,` by `^,` in variable `FID` before the inner loop runs: `set "FID=!FID:,=^,!"`

Comment: I have included that comma(,) to get separate from the Group Variable
    
   <b>echo !FID!,%%~b</b>

I actually need to run this part in inner loop which eventually not running

<b>'net user !FID! /domain^|findstr /b "Global Group memberships"'</b>

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your script there are a couple of obvious issues:

1. Your tokens and delimiters appear to be wrong
2. Your second `FindStr` search mask is incorrect.

I cannot replicate your output here, so the following example script code is based purely on my best guess.

```bat
@Echo Off

For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=\" %%A In (
    'Net LocalGroup "TectiaUsers"^|FindStr/LIB "EUR\"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=3*" %%C In (
    'Net User "%%B" /Domain^|FindStr/LIB "Global Group memberships"'
) Do Echo %%B,%%D

Pause
```